# The use of -さん when answering about oneself

Tags: grammar, syntax, honorifics

If someone says,

> あなた は Chris-さん です か。
>   Are you Chris?

Do you answer

> Chris です

Or

> Chris-さん です

Comment: This is actually a border-line dupe: [When should one add -san at the end of a name?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/49/when-should-one-add-san-at-the-end-of-a-name)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Chris です。

`さん` is never used (except jokingly perhaps) to refer to oneself. The same goes for other common endings such as `くん`, `ちゃん`, `さま`, `先輩` and `先生`.

That's because these endings usually convey a kind of relation: for instance, `さま` conveys respect, `くん` and `ちゃん` convey some endearment and while `さん` conveys very little meaning, it does convey separation. You can't use `さん` on yourself because it's pointless to specify your relation to yourself. And this is even truer for the other endings.

Comment: Fantastic answer! I thought it was without, but I really needed to confirm. Thankyou.

Comment: Yeah, it's understandable. As far as I can tell, in English you can quote and say "Yeah, I'm Mr. so-and-so." - but that doesn't seem to work in Japanese.

Comment: Adding my two cents: The only people I've heard say "[Own name]さん" were men over 60 when introducing themselves. I'm not sure if it was a joke, but no one laughed.

Answer (score 6):

Unless it is some sort of elaborate joke, 
you should not put -さん after your name.

Maybe a story could be helpful...

Once when writing the minutes (議事録 *gijiroku*) of a meeting,
I had to write the list of the participants at the meeting.
I wrote it like this, and then sent the email.

```
●●さん
●●さん
Wallyさん
```

As soon I sent this email, the reaction from my 
coworkers was: "LOL, he put さん to his own name". 
And  tons of 指摘 *shiteki* afterwards.

So yeah, you should never put -san after your name unless you're trying
to be funny. If you want to try to be funny, send an email 
within the mailing list to another coworker without putting -san
to his name. Lots of *shiteki* guaranteed.